# Programme to print all the Prime numbers within a range

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, indentation, break, for-else

So basically the aim of the programme is to print the prime numbers between two numbers.I did find the solution to the problem in the internet but i cannot understand what was worng with my code,I come from a C programming background and now i am learning python, apparently the other solutions use a 'for-else' thing but can  u please spot the logical error or whatever error here?(I am an Undergrad 1st Year student so pls have mercy on me).

`

```
 n1=int(input("Enter the lower limit of the range: "))

 n2=int(input("Enter the upper limit of the range: "))

 prime=True

 for i in range(n1,n2+1):

 if(i>1):
     for j in range(2,i):
         if(i%j==0):
             prime=False
             break
     if(prime==True):
         print(i)       `
```

Comment: Indentation matters in python, can you double check the indentation of your code against the indentation here (which looks like it shouldn't run)

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that once `prime` is set to `False` it will never ever again get to be `True`.

The fix is simple: set it to `True` at the start of every iteration:

```
for i in range(n1, n2 + 1):
    prime = True
    if i > 1:
        for j in range(2, i):
            if i % j == 0:
                prime = False
                break
    if prime:
        print(i)
```

Note that it is not necessary to add parentheses around the `if` condition. Also, it is not necessary to do `prime==True` when `prime` is known to be a boolean. Just test that boolean.

The `i > 1` is a bit overkill. It would be better to start the iteration at *at least* 2 and then never worry about it again:

```
for i in range(max(n1, 2), n2 + 1):
```

And yes, it is a nice feature of Python that a `for` loop can have an `else` clause. It kicks in when the loop finishes normally, without break. In this case it means we can drop the boolean name `prime`.

We get:

```
for i in range(max(2, n1), n2 + 1):
    for j in range(2, i):
        if i % j == 0:
            break
    else:
        print(i)
```